# import .car file in IBM WebSphere 8

Tags: ibm-was

I am very new to WebSphere. I have managed to install `.war` file successfully but application is not starting/running. I found it is depending on Environment settings and other parameters from log file.

Now I have a `.car` file which on import will complete all settings and my application will run without any issues.

Please help me how to import `.car` file into WebSphere.

Answer (score 4):

This has been tested with Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5

1. Start your Websphere server using Eclipse or from command prompt.
2. Navigate to `%WAS_INSTALL_DIR%\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile_name\bin`.
3. Launch ***wsadmin*** batch script and login using your profile security credentials.
4. Use the following commands

   ```
   $AdminTask importWasprofile {-archive c:\backup\was_restore.car}

   $AdminConfig save
   ```

Further details can be found at:
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207526

Comment: WAS 8.5 is installed but unable to start because of error "WCMD0002E: Command "startServer.bat" requires a profile.". How can I import a profile to WAS without even starting it. I already have a *.car created which I can import. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

See details about importing `car` files here - [ConfigArchiveOperations command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_atconfigarchive.html?lang=en).

If you exported whole profile, then to import use:

```
AdminTask.importWasprofile('[-archive c:/myCell.car]')
```

Instead of `car` files, you can consider also using property based configuration - [Using properties files to manage system configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_property_configuration.html?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have executed the above command. 
Now I am getting error:
com.ibm.wsspi.configarchive.ConfigArchiveException com.ibm.wsspi.configarchive.ConfigArchiveException: fail to deploy application isclite

I searched for solution
WASPreUpgrade and WASPostUpgrade will help but Iam struck here also
 cmd:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin>WASPreUpgrade.bat "C:\CCM\Backup File" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer"

Error:
MIGR0272E: The migration function cannot complete the command.

I don't understand what is in the command

Comment: @prashanth `isclite` is admin console, so it is already deployed. Dont use Post/Pre upgrade commands as they are used for version to version migration purposes. You can try reimport with the `-deleteExistingServers true` parameter, it will replace your whole configuration. Before making any changes you should do the `backupconfig` to have backup in case something goes wrong.